# Is there an open source alternative to inSSIDer?

Tags: wireless-networking

inSSIDer was a great tool for scanning wireless networks on Windows, but the newest version has gone from open source to closed source.  The For Home edition only allows for personal use and not business use (EULA doesn't state this currently, but contacting the company revealed they plan on changing the EULA).

Are there any alternatives that are free to use for personal or at work?

Windows 7 64-bit compatibility is required so NetStumbler is out.

I suppose one option would be to use inSSIDer version 2 which is still open source but no longer maintained.  I'd expect that it will stop working eventually though.

Comment: Just used inSSIDer version 2 for debugging a channel overlap problem using Windows 10 x64 on a Surface Pro 4. I'd say it still works well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector:
http://www.xirrus.com/Products/Wi-Fi-Inspector

Download from Cnet to bypass registration. 
http://download.cnet.com/Xirrus-Wi-Fi-Inspector/3000-18508_4-75758254.html

Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector is closed source, however, its license is freeware. It should work well on Windows (x86-x64) XP - 7 (I have tested it on Windows 8).

As for using the old version of inSSIDer, that would work. Based on my basic understanding of inSSIDer, inSSIDer uses Api's found in 90 (ish) percent of Windows computers, and I'll be willing to bet they will continue to be there. At the time that it fails to work (Windows 108 (128-bit)) there will be another program to replace it.